# javascript regular expression for number format

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you suggest a javascript regex to check the number format 1.00.999,000
here '.' represents 100's and ',' represents  decimal points.

Comment: Your example number makes no sense.

Comment: @epascarello - it makes total sense, some locales use `,` as the decimal separator and `.` as the thousand separator, ie the complete opposit eof some other locales :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1.000.999,000  and not 1.00.999,000 though?

Comment: @JohnMitchell - Again, I think thats the weird (to us) way that Indian's represent large numbers.

Comment: @nand could you confirm please how the number system works? Just so we know going forward, the question may teach more than the answer itself :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your just asking for a number format for your exact match then

1.00.999,000 becomes `[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3},[0-9]{3}`

What I suspect you really want may be

```
[0-9]{0,2}(.[0-9]{3})+,[0-9]{0,3}
```

so `two numbers`, followed by any amount of `dot three number` followed by , between `0 and 3 numbers`. I could be wrong in interpreting the number format but I suspect your example of `1.00.999,000` should have an extra zero in the first grouping from the left (000 instead of 00) to make it uniform with the sample after it, or drop the dot between the 1.00.

Answer (score 1):

This will works for number with or without decimals (3 max)

```
[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]{1,3})?
```